OPC UA How to get authentication token from session
I'm trying to construct a requestheader in my OPCUA client, for which I need an authenticationtoken.
Simply accessing via session.AuthenticationToken indicates that the property is protected and thus I cannot access it. I invoke the CreateSession service as follows:
var session = await Session.Create(
    m_configuration,
    endpoint,
    false,
    false,
    m_configuration.ApplicationName,
    60000, new UserIdentity(un, pw),
    null
).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (session.Connected)
{
    m_session = session;
    var authenticationToken = session.AuthenticationToken; <-error here
}

return true;

The only other way I can think to expose the property is by making a custom session class, but I feel like there is a way easier solution/way to go about this that I'm unaware of.
Thanks for the help in advance.
PS.
As mentioned I'm using OPC UA, besides that I'm coding in visual studio C#.
The service I'm trying to call is the DeleteNodes service. I'm following the specification on:
https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part4/v105/docs/5
Where in the table it states that it needs a requestheader.
When clicking on the hyperlink of the requestheader I reach:
https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part4/v104/docs/7.28
I assumed that I would also need an authentication token.

Please add to the description which SDK you use and for which service you need the request header. Normally the SDKs should generate and send the request headers for you. Some services explicitly mention that a null authentication token shall be used.

Hi, thanks for the suggestion; I'm not entirely sure as to what my SDK would be (new to this).
As mentioned I'm using OPC UA, besides that I'm coding in visual studio C#.
The service I'm trying to call is the DeleteNodes service. I'm following the specification on:
https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part4/v105/docs/5
Where in the table it states that it needs a requestheader.
When looking at the following description of the requestheader:
https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part4/v104/docs/7.28
I assumed that I would also need one.

I assume you use the UA-.NetStandard stack then. Normally you should be able to call the services directly from the Session object, like session.Browse and it should do everything for you, but I don't see an interface for the DeleteNodes service.

I have been given a different client in which it looks like I've already found a solution to be able to delete nodes w/o having to create a requestHeader, but instead by using the session.call(...) service. Thanks for the helpt Thibe :)
